# Make Bitbucket README Markdown accept LF in place of CLRF?

Tags: git, bitbucket, markdown, line-endings

I have a list created in my `README.md` that *looks* correct when I view it in Atom:

[image: list markdown in Atom]

But when I upload it to Bitbucket, this list gets completely ignored:
[image]
instead, large parts of it are in italic, indicating to me that Bitbucket doesn't recognise the LF line ending I uploaded to the repo (working on Windows with `autocrlf` enabled).

Is there a way that I can make Bitbucket understand the LF line endings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with line endings. Put a blank line before your list:

```
This is a paragraph followed by

 * some
 * bullet
 * points
```

This is required in many Markdown processors, e.g. here on Stack Overflow. Without the blank line the preceding snippet renders as

> This is a paragraph followed by
>    * some
>    * bullet
>    * points